# Heroku not reflecting changes made to Redmine code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redmine

I'm having an odd and somewhat confusing problem.

I am trying to install Redmine on Heroku. I followed the instructions and well lets say it hasn't been a smooth ride.

I am now trying to do the db:migrate process. (I had to edit all the cruft in the application.rb to get this far, and don't know yet where this will lead.)

In doing the migration however, I get the message

```
Plugins in vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/app/plugins)
```

Through StackOverflow and some other sites, I have found where this message is generated (environment.rb) and have removed the code that generates it.

However, when I push to Heroku and try the migrate again, the same message reoccurs.

I have tried cloning the Heroku repo/app down to a test directory and when I check the environment.rb file, the code is not there, however if I try the migrate (or any rake task for that matter) the message still occurs. Even from the test directory.

I've looked for the same message in other parts of the code, but haven't found it yet. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

There's one of two things at play here

- You're not fixing the problem in your code - running it locally in production mode will show this

OR

- You're not pushing your code to Heroku correctly.  Are you developing on the master branch?  Are you developing in a feature branch?  If so, are you pushing that branch into master on Heroku?  (`git push heroku feature_branch:master`)

Comment: See my answer below, it turns out the reported problem was caused by the environment.rb file being appended to application.rb for some crazy reason. Once I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out what was happening. It's amazing what a good nights sleep can accomplish!

It turns out the cruft in the application.rb file that I mentioned earlier was basically the other files in the config directory appended to app.rb. These included the yml files along with other files like environment.rb and routes.rb. And in amongst this crap was the plugin panic code I had deleted from environment.rb

(It finally came to light when running rake after some changes told me that the application was already initialised!)

So I deleted all this appended nonsense from application.rb and viola! working.

I have no idea why this was done this way as redmine works fine (so far) without it.